# How to add a number in the beginning of a row (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert my column type from object to date. But, I got an error that says

> OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 20-04-09 00:00:00

After looking at the data and trying to find the error, I saw the all the dates that I have has the following format:

```
print(df['date'])

0     020-04-02
1     020-04-02
2     020-04-05
3           NaN
4     020-04-05
        ...   
60          NaN
61    020-04-07
62          NaN
63    020-04-09
64    020-04-09
```

As you can see the dates begin with a zero, so adding a 2 at the beginning will fix the problem for me.
So, the question is, how can I add a 2 while ignoring the NaNs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If add `2` to missing values there are still missing values, so use:

```
pd.to_datetime('2' + df['date'])
```